# Centos 6.6 dual interface

Tags: centos, маршрутизация

Имею centos 6.6, который первоначально находился за NAT. 
Сейчас потребовалось повесить на него отдельный сервис для которого нужен отдельный IP, чтобы не ломать пробросы и не переконфигурировать клиентов которые подвязаны под старый IP - взял дополнительный IP. 
Грубо говоря для нового IP мне нужен доступ из вне, но он даже не пингуется,подскажите что я должен сделать?

ifconfig отображает 2 интерфейса eth0 (старый NAT) и eth1 (новый IP)

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
          inet addr:192.168.10.230  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0


eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
          inet addr:150.90.34.236  Bcast:150.90.34.239  Mask:255.255.255.248
```

route -n

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
150.90.34.232      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.199  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

iptables (INPUT):

```
 Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    num  target     prot opt source               destination         
    1    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    2    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    3    fail2ban-FTP  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 21 
    4    fail2ban-apache-auth  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 80 
    5    fail2ban-SIP  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    6    fail2ban-SIP  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    7    fail2ban-SSH  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 22 
    8    fail2ban-recidive  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    9    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:10051 state NEW 
    10   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:10050 state NEW 
    11   SIP        udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:5060 
    12   SIP        tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:5060
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ не развернутый, а только основная его часть:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter=0
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth1.rp_filter=0
```

Добавить в файл `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`:

```
10 isp1
11 isp2
```

Дальше команды:

```
ip route add default via GW1 table isp1
ip route add default via GW2 table isp2

iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -j CONNMARK --set-mark 10
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -m state --state NEW -j CONNMARK --set-mark 11

iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -j CONNMARK --restore-mark

iptables -t mangle -s GW1 -A OUTPUT -j MARK --set-mark 10
iptables -t mangle -s GW2 -A OUTPUT -j MARK --set-mark 11

ip rule add fwmark 10 table isp1
ip rule add fwmark 11 table isp2
```

После всего этого всё работает.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, открыть порты в `firewalld`:

```
$ firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp
$ firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=443/tcp
$ firewall-cmd --reload
```

Чтобы узнать зону, к которой подключен сетевой интерфейс (в моем примере `public`)

```
$ firewall-cmd --get-zone-of-interface=eth1
```

---

Если используется `iptables`:

```
$ iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
$ service iptables save
$ /etc/init.d/iptables restart
```

Comment: Я использую iptables (добавил раздел INPUT в вопрос). Если я правильно понимаю, то iptables должен пропускать ping и прочие пакеты. Проблема скорее всего в маршрутах, придется использовать mangle...